# Is there a way to obfuscate source SSRS code so it cannot be reverse-engineered?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I work on a team that creates custom SSRS reports for our end users that are viewed using Report Manager or Sharepoint depending on the end user community. Some end users are technical and know how to use BIDS or Visual Studio. This presents a support problem when the end user makes modifications to our reports. I would like to obfuscate our SSRS custom report source to prevent this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not an answer per se, but a query about the basis of your question. Why not just refuse to support modified reports, where the modifications have caused issues (or simply charge a consultancy fee for doing so). This allows you to keep your Support Team's workload at a manageable level but also means your end users retain the ability to make modifications and improvements to reports you have provided.

Comment: Thanks Dan. We also have customers that do a lot of networking and assist each other with common reporting problems (sorry I did not mention this). We are concerned about the sharing of proprietary information. From what I have researched, it is not possible since the rdl files are xml. We could create CLR assemblies, I suppose for our queries, but this is probably overkill. My thought is to just include an intellectual property statement in each rdl.  Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to build your own report viewer, so the rdls could be stored encrypted and decrypted inside the viewer. But this creates a "propietary" solutions which could not be the suitable one for your customer/project.